# NoSuchBeanException, even when Bean is defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have 2 classes.

Target.java: Class to be tested

Helper.java: Helper class

```
@Component
public class Helper {

  public void helperMethod() {
    // some code
  }
}

@Service
public class Target {
  private final Helper helper;

  public Target(Helper helper) {
    this.helper = helper;
  }

  public void someMethod() {
    helper.helperMethod();
  }
}
```

I am testing someMethod() method of Target class. But when running the test case it gives following error:

**Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.abc.def.Helper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.**

Other answers that I have seen for similar question were because of not writing @Component, but I have done that too.

Comment: Some more information is necessary. What is the configuration class you are using ? What is the package of configuration class and your helper class.

Comment: Configuration class in some other package. Also, as this is a spring boot project, all Components are scanned automatically. So I doubt if I have to scan separately.

Comment: ok. Did you also confirm the configuration class is 1 package above the Helper class ? Is the same configuration class getting used in test class ? You can enabled debug mode (pass vm argument to test class -Ddebug) and see if the Helper class gets added to context or not

Comment: What's your configuration? xml or annotation? You're using constructor injection, maybe change to @Autowired

Comment: @PatrickChen annotation based

Comment: Check your @ComponentScan package set, is it include the helper class

Comment: I am not registering Helper bean separately. So I don't understand what it has to do with configuration class. As I am declaring it using @Component, it should register automatically.

Comment: There is no ComponentScan, it is a spring boot project. Scanning happens automatically for the whole base package.

Comment: @RajyawardhanSinghPanwar, if there is no componentscan, how do you expect the Spring container to find your `@Component` annotation and create the bean?

Comment: ComponentScan is enclosed within @SpringBootApplication. However, I have also tried defining a custom scan. @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.abc.def"}). Still, same result.

Comment: Add `@Autowired` annotation for your constructor

Comment: Are you testing using JUnit? Does the application run normally by itself, but the problem arises only when running tests?

Comment: share your test class code

Answer (score 0):

You have provided the correct annotations for the 2 classes in order to ensure that spring treats them as a component and manage their life cycles. Now, if you want to use these beans in any part of the application you would need to declare the dependency for that, the easiest way is as below by using the `@Autowired` annotation, there are mulitple ways to define dependency and you can choose the best options for your use case [accordingly](https://www.baeldung.com/inversion-control-and-dependency-injection-in-spring):

```
@Service
public class Target {
  @Autowired
  private final Helper helper;

  public Target(Helper helper) {
    this.helper = helper;
  }

  public void someMethod() {
    helper.helperMethod();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but I also had similiar issue when writing tests for my application using JUnit. My workaround was to put in my TestClass configuration where I define beans which i need for testing. E.g.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestSomeService {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestSomeServiceConfiguration {  

        @Bean
        public Helper helper() { return new Helper(); }

        @Bean
        public Target targer() { 
            return new Target(
                helper()
            );
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    private Target targetUnderTest;

    @Test
    public void testTarget() {
    }

}
```